# Using Apache Airflow to Automate SSRS and/or SSIS

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, airflow, ssrs-2012

Does it make sense to use Apache Airflow to orchestrate/automate ETLs, and subsequently dispatch reports via SSRS or SSIS?  Put another way, I'm wondering if I can wire up an Airflow DAG to SSRS or SSIS.  The [MsSqlOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql/stable/operators.html) Airflow operator looks like it interfaces with SQL Server, but I can't find any reference to a provider for SSRS or SSIS.

This is meant a very general question, I'm looking for directional guidance, as opposed to code examples (although I'll happily take those). Just wanting to know if I am going to pursue something that isn't going to work or is otherwise a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're looking to orchestrate the running of a report or running of an SSIS package, yeah sure, that's doable.

### SSIS

Assuming you're working with the project deployment model, a package run is a few stored procedure calls strung together

- create_execution creates an instance of an execution
- set_execution_parameter_value allows you to configure values for an instance of that execution
- start_execution begins the actual running of the package

Depending on whether you want the package running in synchronous or asynchronous (default) mode, you might want to set the SYNCHRONIZED bit.

### SSRS

I'm not sure what you're looking for here but we trigger the proc add_event to kick off a subscription which then gets emailed out but I have seen plenty of questions from people that want to run an ssis package that pulls a report and exports to csv/pdf/etc

https://businesswintelligence.com/content/26/manually-trigger-ssrs-subscription

### Docs/Learn

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-create-execution-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-ver16
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-set-execution-parameter-value-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-ver16
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-start-execution-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-ver16
- https://andyleonard.blog/2015/11/the-synchronized-ssis-execution-parameter/

Comment: I really like this guy's (it's not me!) explanation of running a package with SQL. https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2016/11/28/a-better-way-to-execute-ssis-packages-with-t-sql/